Create subnet variable for delegation
My code for Azure subnet delegation is failing. I need your help to resolve this problem, thank you. Here is by error the code is next. The error I get has something to do with the for each call in my nested block for subnet delegation. I will also accept a solution for the same task, which is to have 1 subnet variable.
Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on main.tf line 26, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet":
│   26:       actions = each.value["actions"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 5 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure geographic location for virtual network."
}

variable "address_space" {
  description = "Cidr block for virtual network."
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "Public and private subnets for virtual network"
  type = map(object({
    name                                      = string
    address_prefixes                          = list(string)
    service_endpoints                         = optional(list(string))
    private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = optional(bool)

    delegation = optional(object({
      name = string
      service_delegation = object({
        actions = list(string)
      })
    }))
  }))

  default = {
    subnet1 = {
      name             = "tfakazurepub-vnet-pub-sub"
      address_prefixes = ["192.168.0.0/29"]
    }

    subnet2 = {
      name                                      = "tfakazurepub-vnet-pri-sub"
      address_prefixes                          = ["192.168.0.128/25"]
      service_endpoints                         = ["Microsoft.Storage", "Microsoft.Keyvault"]
      private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = true
    }

    subnet3 = {
      name              = "tfakazurepub-vnet-ppsqldb-sub"
      address_prefixes  = ["192.168.0.16/29"]
      service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage"]

      delegation = {
        name = "pgfs"
        service_delegation = {
          name    = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
          actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
  service_endpoints    = each.value.service_endpoints
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = each.value.private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled

  delegation {
    name = each.value.name
    service_delegation {
      name    = each.value.name
      actions = each.value["actions"]
    }
  }
}

Create a delegated subnet for Postgres

To create multiple subnets and add delegation to a specific subnet, you can use the dynamic block.
dynamic "delegation" { for_each = lookup(each.value, "delegation", null) != null ? [each.value.delegation] : []

Here is the updated Terraform code to create subnets and add delegation to a specific subnet.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "network-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "Azure geographic location for virtual network."
  default     = "East US"
}

variable "address_space" {
  description = "CIDR block for virtual network."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "Public and private subnets for virtual network"
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    address_prefixes = list(string)
    service_endpoints = optional(list(string))

    delegation = optional(object({
      name = string
      service_delegation = object({
        name    = string
        actions = list(string)
      })
    }))
  }))

  default = {
    subnet1 = {
      name             = "tfakazurepub-vnet-pub-sub"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
    }

    subnet2 = {
      name             = "tfakazurepub-vnet-pri-sub"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
      service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage", "Microsoft.Keyvault"]
    }

    subnet3 = {
      name             = "tfakazurepub-vnet-ppsqldb-sub"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
      service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage"]

      delegation = {
        name = "pgfs"
        service_delegation = {
          name    = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
          actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtual_network" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = var.address_space
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
  service_endpoints    = lookup(each.value, "service_endpoints", null)
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  dynamic "delegation" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "delegation", null) != null ? [each.value.delegation] : []

    content {
      name = delegation.value.name
      service_delegation {
        name    = delegation.value.service_delegation.name
        actions = delegation.value.service_delegation.actions
      }
    }
  }
}

Output:

Portal output:

Update:
Another way to achieve the same goal without using the dynamic block. Instead, you can create two separate azurerm_subnet variables with delegation and one for those without delegation
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "network-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtual_network" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "West Europe"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
variable "subnets_without_delegation" {
  description = "Public and private subnets for virtual network without delegation"
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    address_prefixes = list(string)
    service_endpoints = optional(list(string))
  }))

  default = {
    subnet1 = {
      name             = "tfakazurepub-vnet-pub-sub"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
    }

    subnet2 = {
      name             = "tfakazurepub-vnet-pri-sub"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
      service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage", "Microsoft.Keyvault"]
    }
  }
}

variable "subnets_with_delegation" {
  description = "Subnets with delegation for virtual network"
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    address_prefixes = list(string)
    service_endpoints = optional(list(string))

    delegation = object({
      name = string
      service_delegation = object({
        name    = string
        actions = list(string)
      })
    })
  }))

  default = {
    subnet3 = {
      name             = "tfakazurepub-vnet-ppsqldb-sub"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
      service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage"]

      delegation = {
        name = "pgfs"
        service_delegation = {
          name    = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
          actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_without_delegation" {
  for_each = var.subnets_without_delegation

  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
  service_endpoints    = lookup(each.value, "service_endpoints", null)
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_with_delegation" {
  for_each = var.subnets_with_delegation

  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
  service_endpoints    = lookup(each.value, "service_endpoints", null)
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  delegation {
    name = each.value.delegation.name
    service_delegation {
      name    = each.value.delegation.service_delegation.name
      actions = each.value.delegation.service_delegation.actions
    }
  }
}

Output:

Portal Result:


Thanks for your answer. This line of code is a bit new for me. dynamic "delegation" { for_each = lookup(each.value, "delegation", null) != null ? [each.value.delegation] : [] . Do you have perhaps another way to do this if you can spare the moment. Thanks very much again.

Hi @user23350878, I have updated an answer with another approach. Let me know if still need any help from my end.

Thank you. This really is going to make my weekend. I appreciate it. On behalf of the community. Thanks

OK why am I getting this??
